# Stuck with a strange functions to derivate

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to compute the derivative of a function in order to run an algorithm, but I am having a hard time in there: I don't know how to compute the derivative of a recursive function, and there is quite much here.

The base function to derivate is the following:

$$\alpha_i(k) = w_i(k)\frac{C_i}{Q_i}\sqrt{\frac{2\eta_i\Delta t}{C_i}}$$

Where $C_i, Q_i,\eta_i,\Delta t$ are constant. The problem is that $w_i(k)$ is recursive, and it is written like this:

$$w_i(k) = \frac{1}{F_i(k)D_i(k) + \epsilon}$$

We have $F_i(k+1) = F_i(k) + \frac{C_i}{Q_i}\Big(-V_i(k) + \sqrt{V_i(k)^2 + \frac{2\eta_iP_i(k)\Delta t}{C_i}}\Big)$ and another recursive formula for $V_i(k)$ ... It looks kind of overwhelming, especially because the only way for me to compute $P_i(k)$ in the previous equation is to compute $\alpha'_i(k)$ ...

I am a bit lost in this, anyone knows a way to do it correctly ?

Best regards.

Comment: If $F$ is only defined at integers, there is no derivative that can be computed. And if $P$ depends on $\alpha'$, even $\alpha$ can't be computed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. F gives a value between 0 and 1, and even V gives a constant. I have probably missed something. Will do another reading and came back.

Comment: Ok, I have miss read a part of the paper. Alpha prime is not the derivative of alpha ... Quite confusing notation.